# udev rule for binderfs does not create /dev/binder devices on Linux 5.4

Tags: linux, kernel, android, udev

I'm trying to work with the binder driver on a modern Linux 5.4 Kernel system, (5.4.104),
my kernel config enabled the following options:

```
CONFIG_ANDROID=y
CONFIG_ANDROID_BINDER_IPC=y
CONFIG_ASHMEM=y
CONFIG_ION=y
CONFIG_ION_SYSTEM_HEAP=y
CONFIG_ANDROID_BINDER_DEVICES="binder,vbinder,hwbinder"
```

I've added udev rules for binder in order to load them,

```
KERNEL=="binder", MODE="0666"
```

However, I do not see any binder device being created in my /dev/
I can only guess that my udev rule is wrong, but I do not understand what is wrong there.
Can anyone assist in understanding this issue?
I can manually mount binderfs if i type

> mount -t binder binder /dev/

but the udev rule does not work :(